# Combining two arrays into 1 in Python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, data-structures

I have two arrays: vx and vz (shape() = 14502 x 36)) that I want to combine into one array that contains the velocity vector created from the two components (vx and vz).

V = (vx, vz)

Example:

```
vx = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
vz = [(-1,-2,-3),(-4,-5,-6)]
```

I need V to be an array where the shape is the same, but each element contains both the vx and vz data. I'm sure this is basic formatting in Python, but I am having difficulty getting it straightened out.

```
#Expected outcome: V = [(1,-1) (2,-2) (3,-3); (4,-4) (5,-5) (6,-6)]
```

Or even simpler: a new array where Column 1 is column 1 from Vx and Column 2 is column 1 from Vz and so on.

```
#Expected outcome: V = [(1,-1,2,-2,3,-3),(4,-4,5,-5,6,-6)]
```

Comment: Can you add to your example what the final solution would look like

Comment: Python I know, this math I do not. Explain what is supposed to happen and show sample output and you may get more help.

Comment: what do you mean by shape is the same?

Comment: Do you mean the vector sum of (the vectors in) vx and vz?

Comment: I just mean I simply want the information combined so that Column 1 of the V array would contain (vx, vz) from Column 1 of vx and vz arrays. The goal after creating this V array would be to perform the dot product of each element (vx, vz) with the normal vector I calculated in another program.

Comment: still unclear. Add the example of the desired output. Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array of vectors in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> V = np.array([vx, vz]).T      # create numpy array and transpose
>>> V[0, 0]
array([ 1, -1])
>>> V[1, 0]
array([ 2, -2])
>>> V[0, 1]
array([ 4, -4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a nested list comprehension using 2 `zips`:

```
>>> [(x,y) for v,w in zip(vx,vz) for x,y in zip(v,w)]
[(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), (4, -4), (5, -5), (6, -6)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I just wanted to create a new array. No math. Pacholik below answered what I needed.

Comment: @Tbevans88 I changed it in response to your edit. Use it if you want a pure Python (non-numpy) solution (by the way -- you should accept Pacholik's solution if it works for you)